# How to store String Enums with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I can't save data as enum in Realm. When I track the state of a variable, and save, the old value remains, instead of the new one. What am I doing wrong?

I used a setter and a getter, but still the problem is not solved.

```
import RealmSwift

class Transaction: Object {

var accounting: Accounting = .income
@objc dynamic var amount = 0
@objc dynamic var date = ""
@objc dynamic var note = ""

private var privateCategory: String = Category.noCategories.rawValue
var category: Category {
    get { return Category(rawValue: privateCategory)! }
    set { privateCategory = newValue.rawValue }
  } 
}

enum Category: String {
   case noCategories = "No сategories"
   case food = "Food"
   case cafesAndRestaurants = "Cafes And Restaurants"
   case manufacturedGoods = "Manufactured Goods"
   case forceMajeure = "Force Majeure"
   case entertainment = "Entertainment"
}
```

When I try to save a property, the Сategory is saved by default("No categories")

```
let transactionOne = Transaction()
    transactionOne.accounting = .consuption
    transactionOne.amount = 250
    transactionOne.category = .food
```

> transaction   privateCategory String  "No categories"

Comment: You forgot to mark it as `@objc dynamic`.

Comment: it is not working =/

Comment: Even with `@objc dynamic`? Try removing the `private` modifier.

Comment: Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: No, mark `privateCategory` as `@objc dynamic` and remove `private`.

Comment: You mean like this? 
@objc dynamic var privateCategory: String = Category.noCategories.rawValue
    var category: Category {
        get { return Category(rawValue: privateCategory)! }
        set { privateCategory = newValue.rawValue }
    }

Comment: Yes. Did it work?

Comment: No, error...
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Transaction.privateCategory' has been added." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'Transaction.privateCategory' has been added., Error Code=10}

Comment: Delete the app on the simulator first, then run it again. See also: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#migrations

Comment: Wow! It's working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192972/discussion-between-sweeper-and-mikhail-tseitlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from all the examples in the [Realm guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#models), string properties that you want to persist are marked with `@objc dynamic`. So you should mark `privateCategory` as `@objc dynamic` too:

```
@objc dynamic var privateCategory: String = Category.noCategories.rawValue
```